# How do I set up both a landing page and front page?

Tags: 7

Here's the behavior I'm trying to achieve.

If a user types in our domain name www.mysite.com, I want them to go to one page, describing our site.  It can be called www.mysite.com/landing.

But if they hit the logo or the home button anywhere in the site, I want them to go a different page, the one defined in Configuration->Site Information.  It is called www.mysite.com/phront.

Ideas?

Comment: Why not just make the "landing" page the front page in your Site config and link the logo and "home" buttons to the alternate homepage?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, the only problem I see is that the "home"link in the breadcrumb (if you have one) will lead you back to /landing page if /landing is set as the front page in your Site Config. If you have "home" in your menu bar only, then that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

It’s as simple as sheena_d already commented on your answer. Define `/landing` as your home page and link your logo and home button to `/phront`. Done!